# Does anything need to be changed with cassette?

Tags: cassette

I am looking at getting a new cassette for my mountain bike ,and wondering if i need to change anything else(derailleur,shifter,chain)?

Comment: As well as chain (see answers), if shifting a problem, think about a new shifter cable.

Comment: You need to narrow down the scope of this question with more explicit details on what your current drivetrain consists of and what you're looking to replace your cassette with.

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting a new cassette because it is worn, then you should at least get a new chain at the same time. You should also inspect your chainrings for wear and change them if needed. The derailleurs/shifters would only need to be changed if you get a different number of cogs on the cassette. They can wear out, but it's not usually in sync with the other items.

Comment: While doing your inspection don't over look the derailleur pulleys. Most are  plastic with a simple sleeve bearing.

Answer (score 0):

New cassette needs new chain, but not really necessary. If your chain is pretty new (2-3months), you can keep your chain but make sure to give it a good degrease and regrease!